# Looking for the width and height of an html element using jquery closest to find it

Tags: jquery, html, closest

I'm trying to get the dimensions of an element via jquery and I'm not having much luck.

this is how I created my div.

```
var window = document.createElement( 'div' );
window.setAttribute( 'id', 'myWindow' + id );
window.setAttribute( 'data-minwidth', '75' );
window.setAttribute( 'data-minheight', '50' );
window.setAttribute( 'class', 'box_flat' + theme  + '  message' );
window.setAttribute( 'style', 'z-index:' + id );

var content = document.createElement( 'div' );
content.setAttribute( 'id', 'myContent' + id )
content.setAttribute( 'class', 'contents' )
window.appendChild( content );

document.body.appendChild( window )
```

This is how I'm trying to reach it.

```
var cont = $( element ).closest( ".content" ).find( 'div' )
```

element = window in this case.

I always get back an object that looks like a list of selectors. the .width() returns null as does the height. What is a better approach here?

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't redefine the `window` object here.. Use some other name for newly created div.
Also, you don't need `closest()` in this case. Simple `find()` would be sufficient because your `.content` is child of window(which you shall change to something else)

Answer (score 0):

```
var cont = $( element ).find( ".content" );
```

`closest` is used to find the nearest ancestor matching the selector.  `"window"` is not a descendant of `.content` it is a parent.  You use `find` to find descendant element.

On a side note, you probably shouldn't use a variable named "window" as that already has a meaning in javascript.